# "Create database permission can only be granted in the master database" when I'm logged into the master database in Azure Management portal

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I wanted to grand a `CREATE DATABASE` permission inside my SQL Azure Server to a specific user. I went to windows.azure.com, logged in, selected "Database" on the left pane, logged into the "master" database under the database admin account, selected "New Query" - a window with `master: Query(Untitled1.sql)` header appeared.

I typed

> GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO THATUSERLOGIN;

and pressed execute and the query result is

> CREATE DATABASE permission can only be granted in the master database.

What am I doing wrong? How do I do that right?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
USE master
GO
GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO THATUSERLOGIN
```

If that does not help then try to look at the Managing Databases and Logins in SQL Azure guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336235.aspx

Comment: In SQL Azure, you can't use the use statement to switch database contexts.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336288.aspx

Comment: Well, technically you can `USE` the same database. I tried that - doesn't help.